# How to change velocity of startScroll()

Tags: android, textview

I'm using [this](http://goo.gl/RSQIH) answer to implement a marquee `textView` in my app, but I want to be able to change the velocity of it without having to set a duration of the `Scroller`.
If I set a duration for the `Scroller`, then the velocity of the text will be dependent on how much text there is, but what I want is for the velocity to be constant.
Is there any way to do this?
If not, is there any other way to make text automatically scroll at a certain velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the code.

You have to set a duration for the scroller otherwise how would it know how much time to take.

So now we have to make the velocity of the scroller constant.

But `velocity = distance / duration`

So the way to make that constant is to make the duration a function of distance

For eg. IF `duration =2* distance`

`velocity= 2`

and so on.

From the code you've posted

```
     int distance = scrollingLen - (getWidth() + mXPaused);
     int duration = (new Double(mRndDuration * distance * 1.00000
                                  / scrollingLen)).intValue();
```

Now `duration= distance * constant /scrollingLen`

So just remove the `scrollingLen` and it'll be a pure function of distance giving you constant velocity

```
duration= distance * constant /anotherConstant
```

Comment: I completely overlooked that! Thank you very much, I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier!